# Qt Naming Schemes for returns of boolean member variables: enabled(); vs isEnabled(); ?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming, qt, boolean

In building my classes, I have noticed that I have not been very consistent about naming my boolean returns. In Qt; I notice that many of their classes use the `is` prefix, but checking their coding style and conventions, there is no explicit mention that I have seen thus far.

Does the Qt project use a standard or metric for determining when to affix this `is` prefix to boolean returns (If so, what is it?)? Or do they play it by ear and just leave it to the developer's discretion?

Comment: Why would you want a naming convention that is project-specific?  Use the same convention that your programming language uses (unless QT has bindings that assume some particular naming scheme).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I write libraries that I plan to release open-sourced into the Qt community, with the prefix Q to the front of it. I would like to follow their coding standards as best as I can to offer a consistent experience with other Qt Libraries. I'm also interested if they have a rational or principle behind it.

Comment: Have you asked the QT community yet?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was just going to ask here first, figuring the Qt tag would suffice. If no one answered, I would just paste the link in the IRC channel. I like having questions instead of asking the IRC directly, so they don't need to be asked again by anyone else wondering. I hope you understand.

Comment: I would avoid using the prefix Q for your own classes - even if you use namespaces, it will still cause confusion if Qt publish their own class with the exact same name - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921915/should-the-name-of-my-classes-begin-with-q-in-qt